# django-sorting: Localization is not working

Tags: django

I am using django soring application:

https://github.com/directeur/django-sorting

I just wonder if there is a way to make local names for sorting filters...
E.g. I am trying to localize following:

```
<th>{% anchor total Rating %}</th>
```

And using standard django trick

```
<th>{% anchor total _("Rating") %}</th>
```

is not helping... Don't know what to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use the trans template tag from within templates..

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/internationalization/#trans-template-tag

**UPDATE**

If you want the title to be translated, you'll just need to modify the anchor template tag code of django-sorting, for example, looking at the source here:

https://github.com/directeur/django-sorting/blob/master/django_sorting/templatetags/sorting_tags.py

Inside anchor you could modify it, for example, by adding the ugettext function as "_()" when the title is passed to the SortAnchorNode class:

```
return SortAnchorNode(bits[1].strip(), _(title.strip()))
```

Or you can choose another place to fire the translation, this is just for demonstration but it should work

that will translate the title you specify in your tag:

```
{% anchor total "Result" %}  //{% anchor field title %}
```

You need to be sure to have the words you'll pass translated in your dictionaries..

Comment: Looks like the solution did not worked... overlooked that there is not messages in po file :(

Comment: what do you mean? you should add the po files for the words you need to translate

Comment: I mean when I execute django-admin.py compilemessages I see string like #: .\settings.py:27
msgid "English"
msgstr ""    But there is no Result copy there... Among strings of django.po

Comment: makemessages won't find your "Result" string in the template, it will just check your source code where ugettext is used, so you will need to add it by hand in the po file and then use the compilemessages command..

Comment: Trying now... But looks like no success also... The file compiled, but the string is not substituted :(

Comment: The solution I provided DO work, i re-tested it right now with a custom template tag, you're doing something wrong in your template tag maybe.. be sure to use ugettext() instead of ugettext_lazy() for the translation in your template tag, and try to put a word that is present in the standard django.po file (for example {% anchor total "English" %}), I don't know what else can be wrong, you should debug your template_tag code, or post it, if it still doesn't work

Comment: Strange... I am not sure what is wrong. I've changed my code to <th>{% anchor total "English" %}</th> and it doesn't work... But from the other hand same word is not working for locale switching too... e.g. here:    <select name="locale" onchange="$('#locale_switcher').submit()">
            {% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
            <option value="{{ lang.0 }}" {% ifequal lang.0 LANGUAGE_CODE %}selected="selected"{% endifequal %}>{{ lang.1 }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
   </select>

Comment: other messages seems to be translated fine... (I mean those which are from {% trans "" %})

Comment: there's something wrong with the translation inside your template tag I think, I can't help without looking at it